# Ubuntu to XP remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-xp, rdp, remmina

I'm trying to remote desktop connect to my windows XP laptop from my Ubuntu machine.
I am using Remmina Desktop Client. Both the computers in question are at home and both are on the same wireless internet connection. I don't know what information to put in what fields in the Remmina Profile box.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: we can't see what fields are there on the profile box. Add a screenshot or describe the fields

Comment: @Sathya: just take a second to run `remmina`!

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 3):

Try these -- you will just need the IP address of the XP machine, and your username and password on that computer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Turns out I was using the correct procedure with the wrong IP address.

Comment: Please accept as the answer in that case (tick mark on left side), so the question is marked as "answered" and closed :)